# How can I convert images to a pdf document go lang?

Tags: go, pdf-generation

I am trying to make a small tool to download images from websites and automatically convert them to PDF. I have tried looking for go lang libraries to convert images to pdf however most of them are related to converting to pdf to images and even in the libraries such as [Maroto](https://github.com/johnfercher/maroto) and [GofPdf](https://github.com/jung-kurt/gofpdf) they don't go into details on how to convert a directory full of images into a pdf file. I have done this in python but it's super slow for my use case.

Comment: https://github.com/unidoc/unipdf-examples/blob/master/image/pdf_images_to_pdf.go unidoc looks like a good library choice.  You'll have to iterate over the directory yourself, but that code shows you `NewImageFromFile` which seems like the PDF side of what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PdfCpu works great:

```
pdfcpu import out.pdf a.jpg b.jpg
```

https://pdfcpu.io/generate/import